# How to call function in view from controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I want the function randstring call into the view input. Please help someone if knows.

```
class Quote extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {        
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model_quote');
    } 
    public function randstring(){
        $characters = '0123456789';
        $randomString = 'Q';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {$randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];}
        $random = $randomString;
        $r = $this->db->get_where('quotation_parent',array('qoute_no'=>$random))->row_array();
        if(!empty($r)){
            $this->randstring();
        }else{
            return $r['qoute_no'];  
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: One of the key points of MVC is you don't have logic (functions) declared in your views - views are essentially just templates, with PHP used only to echo values.

Comment: Move your function in helper.php and then use.

Comment: using  AJAX will helps to access outside functions.

Comment: Also your logic should be in a model not your controller

Comment: Use prebuilt `string` [helper](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/string_helper.html) and `random_string()` function from there. Check other functions too.

Comment: Can you please explain your question as if you want to call `randstring` from view/ajax ?